# unable to copy from buffer to image

Tags: vulkan

I have an image of dimensions `4096*4096` (so `67108864` bytes, since there are 4 channels) that I want to copy from a staging buffer to a device local image. The buffer already has the data stored and I have set up the image barriers properly, so now I want to perform the copy operation... Except it doesn't work. The validation layers give me this error message when I call `vkCmdCopyBufferToImage()` -

`IMAGE(ERROR): object: 0x0 type: 6 location: 3903 msgCode: 417333590: vkCmdCopyBufferToImage(): pRegion[0] exceeds buffer size of 67108864 bytes. The spec valid usage text states 'The buffer region specified by each element of pRegions mustbe a region that is contained within srcBuffer' (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkCmdCopyBufferToImage-pRegions-00171).`

I can't find anything wrong with the values that I gave it though. The `VkBufferImageCopy` struct I passed to it looks like this-

```
        VkBufferImageCopy bufImgCopy;
        bufImgCopy.bufferOffset = 0;
        bufImgCopy.bufferImageHeight = 0;
        bufImgCopy.bufferRowLength = 0;
        bufImgCopy.imageExtent = modelTexture.imgExtents; // 4096 * 4096 * 1
        bufImgCopy.imageOffset = {0, 0, 0};
        bufImgCopy.imageSubresource.aspectMask = modelTexture.subResource.aspectMask; // Colour attachment
        bufImgCopy.imageSubresource.baseArrayLayer = modelTexture.subResource.baseArrayLayer; // 0
        bufImgCopy.imageSubresource.layerCount = VK_REMAINING_ARRAY_LAYERS;
        bufImgCopy.imageSubresource.mipLevel = 0;
```

I can't figure out why the api thinks the struct is specifying a size greater than the buffer size. The format of the image is `VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM`.

**EDIT**

Here's the code that sets up the staging buffer-

```
stageBuf.usage = VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT;
stageBuf.shareMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
stageBuf.bufSize = static_cast<VkDeviceSize>(verts.size() * sizeof(vert) + indices.size() * sizeof(u32)) > modelImage.size ? static_cast<VkDeviceSize>(verts.size() * sizeof(vert) + indices.size() * sizeof(u32)) : modelImage.size;

// filled from the previous struct.
VkBufferCreateInfo info;
info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BUFFER_CREATE_INFO;
info.pNext = nullptr;
info.flags = 0;
info.queueFamilyIndexCount = bufInfo.qFCount;
info.pQueueFamilyIndices = bufInfo.qFIndices;
info.usage = bufInfo.usage;
info.sharingMode = bufInfo.shareMode;
info.size = bufInfo.bufSize;

if (vkCreateBuffer(device, &info, nullptr, &(bufInfo.buf)) != VK_SUCCESS)
{ //...

VkMemoryRequirements memReqs;
vkGetBufferMemoryRequirements(device, buf, &memReqs);

for (u32 type = 0; type < memProps.memoryTypeCount; ++type)
    if ((memReqs.memoryTypeBits & (1 << type)) &&
        ((memProps.memoryTypes[type].propertyFlags & memFlags) == memFlags)) // The usual things to set buffers up.
    {
        VkMemoryAllocateInfo info;
        info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_INFO;
        info.pNext = nullptr;
        info.allocationSize = memReqs.size;
        info.memoryTypeIndex = type;

        if (vkAllocateMemory(device, &info, nullptr, &mem.memory) == VK_SUCCESS)
        { //....

    // All this works perfectly except for the texture copy.
    if (vkBindBufferMemory(device, buf, mem.memory, mem.offset) != VK_SUCCESS)
    { //...
```

I'm using this staging buffer for both the vertex and index buffers (which I have taken as a single buffer with offsets) as well as the image which I'm trying to copy to. The memory allocated is according to the size of the largest data structure.

Comment: How many array layers has the image? Only one or more?

Comment: Only one. It also has 4 mipmap layers.

Comment: Where do You provide the number of mipmap levels to copy? I don't have spec at this moment and I don't remember all the parameters of buffer image copy. And why there are two variables *bufImgCopy* and *bufImgCopies*?

Comment: the spec says `VkBufferImageCopy` has a `VkImageSubresourceLayers` member, which allows a single mipmap level to be specified along with the number of layers and the first layer. You can see it in the snippet above. That `bufImgCopies` thing is just a formatting mistake on my part, I'll edit it out.

Comment: Can you add the actual code that sets up and uploads the staging buffer. The buffer image copy structure looks fine, so the interesting part might be where you upload data. Also try setting the layerCount to 1 instead of using VK_REMAINING_ARRAY_LAYERS.

Comment: Could You also show us the code in which You copy data from the buffer to the image?

Comment: @SaschaWillems `VK_REMAINING_ARRAY_LAYERS` is invalid for `VkImageSubresourceLayers`. You should make that answer.

Comment: @krOoze  Yes, that fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments. Using `VK_REMAINING_ARRAY_LAYERS` is invalid for the `layerCount` of `VkImageSubresourceRange`, so you have to explicitly set the `layerCount` to the actual number of layers to copy.